# PDF not quite displaying correctly after switching from a form submit to ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web application that takes some user inputs, sends them off to a backend service (which I can't modify) which uses xPression to generate the PDF data, and then opens the PDF in a new tab.

It used to do this with a form submit, but the client wants the app to handle errors, so I've had to switch it to ajax. I've got this just about working, except things like images, trademark symbols, and text bolding aren't showing up correctly.

Here's the code for the old version, which basically created a form and submitted it, opening the result in a new tab:

```
  var pdfForm = document.createElement('form');
  pdfForm.setAttribute('id', 'pdfForm');
  pdfForm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
  pdfForm.setAttribute('action', model.url());
  pdfForm.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  var reportRequest = document.createElement('input');
  reportRequest.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  reportRequest.setAttribute('name', 'reportRequest');
  reportRequest.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(model.attributes));
  pdfForm.appendChild(reportRequest);
  document.body.appendChild(pdfForm);

  pdfForm.submit();
  pdfForm.remove();
```

And here's what it looks like (mostly, I had to sanitize it a bit with MSPaint for client confidentiality):
[image]

Here's the code for the new way, which serializes the form and sends the data in an ajax request so that it can handle the errors:

```
  var pdfForm = document.createElement('form');
  pdfForm.setAttribute('id', 'pdfForm');
  pdfForm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
  pdfForm.setAttribute('action', model.url());
  pdfForm.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  var reportRequest = document.createElement('input');
  reportRequest.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  reportRequest.setAttribute('name', 'reportRequest');
  reportRequest.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(model.attributes));
  pdfForm.appendChild(reportRequest);
  document.body.appendChild(pdfForm);
  var pdfWindow = window.open('loading.html', '_blank');

  var that = this;
  $(pdfForm).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: model.url(),
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(pdfForm).serialize(),
      success: function(data){ 
          /* I cut some irrelevant changes to the main page, like getting rid of a loading spinner, etc */
          pdfWindow.location.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type : 'application/pdf'}));
      },
      error: function(){
         /* I cut some irrelevant error handling */
      } 
    });
  });

  $(pdfForm).submit();
  $(pdfForm).remove();
```

And here's what it looks like with the new method:

[image]

Note that the trademark symbol is garbled, the bolding is missing from the labels, and the company logo image is completely missing.

I assume this is coming down to a URI encoding issue or something like that, but I'm clueless on how to proceed. Basically this displays perfectly when submitted as a form, but garbled when we try to build the same result with the ajax response.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Can you make sure that the pdf produced by the server is correct? To narrow down the issue.

Comment: No errors in the console. And I'm not really sure how to check that the server is producing it correctly beyond the fact that it's the exact same API call and it works perfectly in one instance of me using it but not in the other.